# Web Audio API - loading a file and playing it

Tags: javascript, audio, web

There are some questions similar on SO but it appears the syntax is all deprecated.

I'm trying to load a sound off of my DropBox (public link) and play it at startup of my app.

Here is my code:

```
var context = new webkitAudioContext();
function start() {
// Note: this will load asynchronously
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/86304379/Pt.%205%20Flood%20the%20Soul.wav", true);
request.responseType = "arraybuffer"; // Read as binary data
// Asynchronous callback
request.onload = function() {
    var data = request.response;

    audioRouting(data);
};
request.send();
}
function audioRouting(data) {
    source = context.createBufferSource(); // Create sound source
    buffer = context.createBuffer(data, true/* make mono */); // Create source buffer from raw binary
    source.buffer = buffer; // Add buffered data to object
    source.connect(context.destination); // Connect sound source to output
    playSound(source); // Pass the object to the play function
}
    // Tell the Source when to play
function playSound() {
    source.noteOn(context.currentTime); // play the source immediately
}
```

Alas - I call playSound() in one of my functions and I get

"Cannot call method 'noteOn' of undefined "

Is this because noteOn is deprecated? Or is something else amiss. I just want to load some audio into an audio node and play it - I have not found any ample code online that displays how to do this.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

Comment: @phenomnomnominal I have tried that before, but for the life of me could not actually play the sound. Calls to playsound yield "Failed to set the 'buffer' property on 'AudioBufferSourceNode': buffer cannot be null ". I don't know what it wants as an argument. I don't know how to make it not null. The lack of good examples and documentation for this stuff is really sad. It's just people trying to copy and paste and failing.

Comment: I'll whip up an example for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, the `noteOn` function is indeed gone, now it is `start`:

```
user:        crogers
date:        Tue Sep 25 12:56:14 2012 -0700
summary:     noteOn/noteOff changed to start/stop -- added deprecation notes
```

The API is as good as you will get for the docs - the [AudioBufferSourceNode](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#AudioBufferSourceNode-section) section is the bit you want for this.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/bbW62/1/) an example of how I do it (excuse the CoffeeScript).

Answer (score 0):

The above is correct, noteOn is deprecated.  But because we cannot be sure if a user will visit with an older browser that only supports deprecated calls or a new browser that only supports new calls, [SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS) sets up compatibility for both by mapping the calls.  Check out [WebAudioPlugin._compatibilitySetUp](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/blob/master/src/soundjs/WebAudioPlugin.js) if your interested.